# Error with nested urls in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm using AngularJs and I'm having a problem in routes.
I have this two urls:

/:blog

/:blog/:post

When I'm listing blogs and click in post, the URL is changed and all things works like a charm. But if I reload the page, the Angular is opening the wrong route.

This is my code:

```
.when('/:blog', {
  // If I reload the page, the angular choose this route
  templateUrl: '/templates/blogs/show.html',
  controller: 'BlogController',
  resolve: {
    initialData: ["BlogInitialData", function(BlogInitialData){
      return BlogInitialData();
    }]
  }
})
.when('/:blog/:post', {
  templateUrl: '/templates/posts/show.html',
  controller: 'PostController',
  resolve: {
    initialData: ["PostInitialData", function(PostInitialData){
      return PostInitialData();
    }]
  }
})
```

Please, help me!
I tried to change order, but didn't work too.

****************** EDITED **************************

I discovered the problem, but I cannot solve this one.
When I access the /:blog/:post, for example.
http://website.com/blog-name/post-slug, the angular is considering the route like /:blog with the value "post-slug". Is the same if I access onlye "/post-slug" route.

If I put a slash (/) in the end, the angulas is considering the route like only a slash. For example:

/blog-name/post-slug/ -> Calling index route

How can I solve this?

Comment: which url is not working? `/:blog/:post` or `/:blog` ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forget to explain this.
The /:blog/:post is wrong.

The angular is considering the otherwise in the last rule.

Comment: are you sure it doesn't contain extra `/` at the end of url like `/:blog/:post/`..that will mess

Comment: My Angulas is very crazy!
I tried this now, and the route bring me the home page (only "/")

Comment: I edited the post. I discovered an error, but I cannot solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are experiencing is AngularJs's lack of nested views routing system. The reason why it works when you click it is because it *does* changes the template but it can't interpret what you are trying to do from the URL alone so when you refresh it doesn't know what to do and takes you to the first valid piece of the URL which is the first view `/:blog`. Your solution might be in things like Angular-ui-route.

Comment: J_Amando. I changed my angular.config to Angular-ui-route (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#get-started) and the same error occurred.

If I change the $locationProvider.html5Mode to false and try to access with hash (#/blog-name/post-slug) all works like a charm.

The problem happens only without hash, changing the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code:
`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`